# In Flutter, Getting API Handshaking Error CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED(399)

Tags: flutter, dart, dio, flutter-http, themoviedb-api

In flutter, API has this error:

> the following handshakeexception was thrown resolving an image codec:
> handshake error in client (os error: certificate_verify_failed: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:393))

[image: certificate_verify_failed]

Comment: The certificate of that website is not expired, and I can access that successfully. Perhaps your proxy has an expired certificate?